# how to print all result in single line

Tags: java, loops

i have loop which is giving me some numbers below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int i = 1; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if (i % 15 ==0) {
            System.out.println("A="+i);
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0 ){
            System.out.println("B="+i);
        }
        else if (i%3==0){
            System.out.println("C="+i);
        }
    }
}
```

its giving me result like

```
C=3
B=5
C=6
C=9
B=10
C=12
A=15
C=18
B=20
C=21
C=24
B=25
C=27
A=30
C=33
B=35
C=36
C=39
B=40
C=42
A=45
C=48
B=50
C=51
```

but i need result like

```
C=3,6,9,12...
B=5,10,20...
A=15,30,45...
```

if someone can help me i will be very grateful
thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to collect all the As, Bs, and Cs into lists, instead of printing them out as you go.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You store all `i` for  `i%15 == 0` into a string - `sA`, `i` for `i%5==0` into `sB` and all `i` for `i%3==0` into third string `sC` - at the end print these three strings.

Comment: Thanks for all your support@Louis @Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would have done it :

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Number>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Number>>();
map.put("A", new ArrayList<Number>());
map.put("B", new ArrayList<Number>());
map.put("C", new ArrayList<Number>());
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) {
        map.get("A").add(i);
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        map.get("B").add(i);
        System.out.println("B=" + i);
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        map.get("C").add(i);
    }
}
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Number>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "=");
    String strResults = Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().toArray());
    System.out.print(strResults.substring(1, strResults.length() - 1));
    System.out.println();
}
```

It can be more generic but it does what it suppose to do.

Comment: Please don't act as a code-writing service for an OP who hasn't shown effort.

Answer (score 0):

With Java8  you can just create a `IntStream` with all the values, partition them with a grouping function and then print them, something like this:

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> mapped = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed()
    .filter(i -> i % 5 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      i -> {
        if (i % 15 == 0) return 'A';
        else if (i % 5 == 0) return 'B';
        else if (i % 3 == 0) return 'C';
        return null;
      })
    );

mapped.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+"= "+v.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
```

Output:

```
A= 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90
B= 5, 10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70, 80, 85, 95
C= 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 33, 36, 39, 42, 48, 51, 54, 57, 63, 66, 69, 72, 78, 81, 84, 87, 93, 96, 99
```

The first part generates a stream with all numbers in range `[0,100)`, then filter out everything that is not divisible by 5 or 3 and then through groupingBy divides them according to its divisor.

The second part just iterates through all the lists and prints them.

Comment: your `mapToObj` can be replaced by `boxed` which seems a bit more explicit IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Java 8 streams:

```
System.out.println("A = " + modList(3));
System.out.println("B = " + modList(5));
System.out.println("C = " + modList(15));

private String modList(int mod) {
    return IntStream.range(1, 100).filter(n -> n % mod == 0).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Or a more generic solution that creates a map in one pass for as many modulos as you want:

```
List<Integer> modList = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 15);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> modMap = modList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), ArrayList::new));
IntStream.range(1, 1000).forEach(n -> modList.stream().filter(mod -> n % mod == 0)
    .forEach(mod -> modMap.get(mod).add(n)));
System.out.println("A = " + modMap.get(3).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store your `As`, `Bs` and `Cs` in [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then print them out. You have to stored them because you can't reprint the results that you print in your console.

For example, if you have one array to each option:

```
ArrayList<int> a = new ArrayList<int>();
ArrayList<int> b = new ArrayList<int>();
ArrayList<int> c = new ArrayList<int>();
```

And in your for loop you have to stored the values that you are getting:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int i = 1; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if (i % 15 ==0) {
            a.add(i);
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0 ){
            b.add(i);
        }
        else if (i%3==0){
            c.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And later you can print them out:

```
System.out.print("A=");

for (int i : a) {
     System.out.print(i);
     System.out.println(",");
}
```

This code will be equals for the `ArrayList` of `Bs` and `Cs` (of course, the specific parts of each `ArrayList` have to change) .

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: To the downvoter: can you explain please what it's wrong on my answer? I want to learn about my errors.

Answer (score -2):

To print in the same line, use [`System.out.print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) instead of println. Then use `\n` or `System.out.println` to create a new line.

In your case, you'll have to store the As, Bs and Cs in an array/list, so you can access them all later to print them.